# create a view like facebook menu navigation in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, facebook, uiview

I need to create a view like below in my iPhone application. And I have no clue how to do it.

Description of the view: If I press the arrow indicated button icon in the view, a new view

will appear on the same view just like a popup. This is a Facebook page. I need to simulate

the same in my iPhone application.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may refer to below links:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X2JKYDF1wbM

Part-1
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tJJMyzdB9uI

Part-2
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HqFFjmhoO1c

Answer (score 4):

Cocoacontrols.com is your friend.  They have several controls that do what you're looking to do.  Check out http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/jasidepanels for example.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. @Ramu Pasupuleti answer gives me an instant solution.

Answer (score 1):

exactly what you want...

http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/jasidepanels

http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/hhtablistcontroller-vertical-tab-view-controller

Happy Coding!!!!!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. @Ramu Pasupuleti answer gives me an instant solution.

Answer (score 0):

JTRevealSidebar use this one. I have used it. its very useful and working same as facebook app

https://github.com/mystcolor/JTRevealSidebarDemo/blob/master/JTRevealSidebarV2/JTRevealSidebarV2Delegate.h

This is not working with iOS7 Giving error "UINavigationControllers are not allowed in a navigation controller!"