# Facebook template xcode iphone

Tags: iphone, xcode, templates, menu

I am doing my first app in xcode for iPhone. I am using xcode 3.2.

I want to use the format of Facebook application (a removable menu in left-hand). I would like to know if this option is a template of xcode (I have seen the same submenu in other applications). Or maybe this template is available in new versions of xcode. I can not found it in my xcode version (or I don't know how I must build it).

So:

1. Is a removable menu in left-hand a template? What is the name of this template?
2. What is the version of xcode in?
3. Can I use this template in xcode 3.2?

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: It's not an application template that is supported in Xcode. The navigation/UI control is not provided by Apple. You'll have to develop it yourself or use a 3rd party library.

Comment: Xcode 3.2 is ancient.  Upgrade.  It's free, and it will hold you back otherwise.

Comment: Thank you. I can not upgrade my xcode because my mac doesn't support Lion. Thank rickerbh for the explanation, I have lost many time looking for this template and finally it doesn't exist, so now I know I must develop it or use a 3rd party library.

Comment: Below link may help:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15215818/create-a-view-like-facebook-menu-navigation-in-iphone/15215949#15215949

Answer (score 1):

That particular control is not an iOS default but rather a third-party library a lot of apps use because it's very effective and good looking. Here is one of the implementations you can use in your project:

http://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/iiviewdeckcontroller

Comment: Thank you very much. It looks like very good. It doesn't work with my xcode but I will try to fix the problems. Thank you again for the link ;)

Comment: You should really update your XCode. The version you're using it almost 3 years old and pretty much obsolete for any viable iOS development.